# Is this contraposition proof complete?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I want to prove the statement If $a>b$ then $X.$

Suppose that I've proved that If $\neg X$ then $a<b.$ This gives $a\leq b,$ which $a<b$ is a subset of.

Can I consider the proof finished, by contraposition?

Comment: That works. Prove that $\neg X$ implies $a<b$ and that it in turn implies $a\leqslant b$. Equivalently, $a>b$ implies $X$. That is if you subscribe to this excluded middle nonsense..

Comment: No. Consider $a=5,b=5$, and $X$ it is raining. If it isn't raining, you have proved $5<5$!

Comment: @JMP I don't follow

Comment: The contrapositive is $\lnot(a>b)$ which is $a\le b$.

Comment: Ok, but how did I prove $5<5$. The contrapositive is, if it is not raining then $5\leq 5$, which is vacuously true. Which proves that if $5>5$ then it is raining, which I guess means it never rains, but I don't get your point.

Comment: @MinecraftPlayer69 No, $5>5$ would be sufficient to rain (if the statement was true). It doesn't follow it never rains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've proved that if $\neg X$ then $a<b$.

Taking the contrapositive: $a\ge b\implies X.\tag1$

And we know that $a>b\implies a\ge b.\tag2$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2):$ $a>b\implies X,\tag3$ as required.

P.S. $(1)$ is a stronger statement than $(3)$ because the former has a less stringent condition for attaining the same result as the latter.

P.P.S. In general, if $(A⇒X)$ and $(Y⇒B)$, then the sentence $(X⇒Y)$ is at least as strong as the sentence $(A⇒B).$ This is because $$\big((A→X)∧(Y→B)\big)→\big((X→Y)→(A→B)\big)$$ is logically true and equivalent to $$\big((A→X)∧(Y→B)∧(X→Y)\big)→(A→B).$$